# Re-connect to a 32 bit MS Access database with 64bit R-Studio, post v1.2 patch using odbc package

Tags: microsoft-access, r, rstudio

My workplace recently updated my R Studio application, and odbc connections to my 32bit MS Access database were broken. As near as I can tell, I lost my 32 bit R option with the update, resulting in a driver conflict.

The issue was brought up and addressed around December, and the re-inclusion of 32bit R support was introduced in patch 1.2. Reference:
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/4775

I currently have R-studio v1.2.1335, and R version 3.5.3 (both 32 and 64 bit) installed on my 64bit windows 10 pc. My R Studio "Tools -> Global Options -> R Version" does not display a 32-bit option, and when I manually select the 32 bit folder it simply returns to the 64bit only screen selection.

It looks like I have the patch that fixes this issue, but I cannot connect to my 32 bit MS Access database using the same code that I used 3 weeks ago. For reference:

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
    driver = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)",
    Dbq = " C:/Users/myname/Documents/R/database.mdb ",
    Uid = "Admin" ,
    Pwd = ""
    )
```

*Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: IM002: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified*

ODBC connection managers list no 64-bit .mdb drivers installed, but 32-bit .mdb drivers are installed.

After seeing the resolution patch 1.2 appears to be installed, I am at a loss as to additional troubleshooting to do. Please and thank you.

Comment: What version of Access are you using? Do you have the 32-bit or 64-bit version of it installed?

Comment: MS Office Professional Plus 2016, including MS Access. 32bit version installed. I am not able to change this part, office software.

Comment: If you have a 32-bit Access installed.  Why are you looking for 64-bit ODBC Access drivers?

Comment: I'm not? I'm trying to determine why my connection to MS Access suddenly stopped working. I provided a list of my currently installed drivers and ELF simply because the error that I am suddenly getting (italics in op) indicates a missing or conflicting driver. 

However, as you noted, I seem to have all the relevant drivers. I also have the v1.2 R-Studio patch that re-introduced 32bit R support, and 32bit R installed, hence my connection to 32bit Access has no reason to be throwing that particular error, that I can determine. 

Apologies if I was vague. I'm new at this.

Comment: Per kevinushey (RStudio Employee) 2018-10-16: "We've removed support for 32-bit versions of R in RStudio v1.2." https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-select-32-bit-r-version-in-rstudio-v1-2-1047-1-preview/16404/2